# How to access images that already uploaded through our own facebook application using facebook php SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having an problem when I want to retrieve all the photos that already uploaded by users using my faceboook web app. Usually I'm doing this to access my application album with facebook php SDK

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'SECRET_ID',
        'cookie' => true
    ));
$app_name = "My Own App";
$jsonalbum = $facebook->api("/USER_ID/albums?fields=id,name")
$album_id = searchAlbum($app_name." Photos", $jsonalbum)
```

I have to doing this with every user that having permission to my app, It's a little bit awful. I just want to ask, is there any ways to retrieve all images based on app that upload it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that there is a way to do exactly what you are asking.

The correct method would be to record all of the images that were uploaded (at the time they were uploaded) and storing their ID's in a database of sorts.

Facebook doesn't really allow users to mine data - as you are requesting. Users are are an entity in and within itself - the fact that the image was uploaded via your application doesn't really come into play here. Once the image has been uploaded it belongs to the user and not to your application.

Perhaps if your images were all uploaded to an album created by your application you'll be able to just request the contents of that album - but if the users have since moved the image to a different album - you won't be able to see that it has been moved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I need that to do picture ranking based on likes. So the possibility is to create own database to store ID's and likes counter?

Comment: Yes - that sounds right. However you still won't be able to query the API to get images that have already been uploaded.

Comment: Ok, maybe i will use two ways of upload, facebook and app server... by the way is it any possibilities to upload on application's album? cause i found that in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/ : The User, Page and Application objects have an albums connection of type album. also there is query to graph api using 'app?fields=albums'. but i don't know how to make user upload to that album, also can;t find where is the album itself